# Run ruby code from a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to run ruby code from inside of a string.

Something like

```
'x = %ruby command%'
```

I have tried this from inside of my GemFile with no luck

```
gem 'private_gem', '>= 2.0.0', :git => 'https://#{ENV['github_user']}:#{ENV['github_password']}@github.umn.edu:asrweb/umn_shib_auth.git'
```

This is the error message

```
[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input - ... => 'https://#{ENV['github_user']}:#{ENV['github_password']}...
...                               ^. Bundler cannot continue.
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use double quotes:

```
gem 'private_gem', '>= 2.0.0', :git => "https://#{ENV['github_user']}:#{ENV['github_password']}@github.umn.edu:asrweb/umn_shib_auth.git"
```

Comment: Clarification: Double quotes (`"..."`) will interpolate on `#{...}`, while single quotes (`'...'`) will not.